# Set RAW as standard on reset Nikon D700

Tags: nikon, raw, nikon-d700

Is there any way to set RAW image quality / file type to be the standard setting when resetting a Nikon D700?

I often/always start a photo shoot by resetting my camera (holding QUAL and +/- for a few settings), and I **always** have to change the image quality to RAW afterwards. It would be nice to not have to do this extra step because

1. it requires me to take an extra step each time I reset the camera
2. if I forget it I end up shooting the entire shoot in JPEG only and
       it basically ruins most of the pictures

Comment: Camera reset should be used only in some rare case, like after you let your little 4 years old cousin play with the dslr and push all the buttons. Why do you need to reset you camera every time ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would go against the purpose of a reset. What is most likely to be *closer* to what you are looking for are custom memory banks. IIIRC, the D700 has 4. You save settings in each bank as you like and then the camera uses them when you select a particular bank. Most but not all settings can be saved this way.